# C++ check inheritance at compile time

Tags: c++, templates

I have a base class

```
template<typename T>
class Base {};
```

and a few derived classes:

```
class DerivedInt : public Base<int> {}
class DerivedDummy : public Base<Dummy> {} 
      // where Dummy is some user-defined concrete type
template<typename E>
class DerivedGeneric : public Base<E> {}
```

I wish to write a type trait function `f<DerivedType>::value` that returns true only when there exists a type `T` such that `DerivedType` inherits from `Base<T>`.

I feel that SFINAE is the way to go ... but I'm not too familiar with the metaprogramming black magic. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An improvement to Mateusz Grzejek's solution to make a real traits:

```
template <class T>
std::true_type is_derived_from_base_t_impl(const Base<T>* impl);

std::false_type is_derived_from_base_t_impl(...);

template <class Derived>
using is_derived_from_base_t =
    decltype(is_derived_from_base_t_impl(std::declval<Derived*>()));
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/qAfigs)

Note that doesn't handle multiple inheritance.

Comment: For some reason, I can't use this type function in `enable_if`. Something like `typename std::enable_if<is_derived_from_base_t<T>(), void>::type` gives me `template argument 1 is invalid`.

Comment: or with `{}` ([Demo](http://ideone.com/j8VOrK)). It seems that `()` introduces vexing parse.

Answer (score 7):

I believe the [type support templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types) in C++11 are what you want, especially [std::is_base_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of).

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, if `std::is_base_of` could be helpful in this case, but you could surely use [std::is_convertible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible).

If there exists type `T`, such that `Derived` inherits from `Base<T>`, it means, that `Derived` is **implicitly-convertible** to `Base<T>`.

So, you can simply use following solution. It is compile-time detection in such way, that it won't compile if you call checking function for type, that does not fulfil your requirements. Check this code:

```
#include <iostream>


struct Dummy
{
};

template<typename T>
class Base
{
};

class DerivedInt : public Base<int>
{
};

class DerivedDummy : public Base<Dummy>
{
};

template<typename E>
class DerivedGeneric : public Base<E>
{
};

template <class T>
bool is_derived_from_base_t_impl(Base<T>* impl)
{
    return true;
}

template <class Derived>
bool is_derived_from_base_t()
{
    Derived* d = nullptr;
    return is_derived_from_base_t_impl(d);
}


int main()
{
    std::cout<< is_derived_from_base_t< DerivedInt >() <<"\n";
    std::cout<< is_derived_from_base_t< DerivedDummy >() <<"\n";
    std::cout<< is_derived_from_base_t< DerivedGeneric<float> >() <<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1
1
1
```

However, if you do:

```
is_derived_from_base_t< float >();
```

You will get:

`error C2784: 'bool is_derived_from_base_t_impl(Base<T> *)' : could not deduce template argument for 'Base<T> *' from 'float *'`

(Output from VC++ 11)

Comment: It can be improved to return false instead of compile error, see my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution. I prefer @Jarod42's code though, because I want to use the return value in static_assert()

Answer (score 0):

Several more aspects answered

* independence from C++11 features
 * private inheritance
 * virtual inheritance
 * multiple inheritance
 * inheritance from struct
 * symmetric relationship, i.e. forward or reverse inheritance

```
/**
 * Class Template InheritanceCheck
 * @param Candidate - type optionally inherited from Base
 * @param Base - base class/struct
 */
template<typename Candidate, typename Base>
class InheritanceCheck
{

    static char Test(Base*);
    static int Test(...);

    static void Constraints(Candidate* p) { }

    InheritanceCheck() 
    {
        void(*p)(Candidate*) = Constraints;
    };

public:
    /**
     *  isSub, true when Candidate is derived from Base
     */
    static const bool isSub = sizeof(Test(static_cast<Candidate*>(0))) == sizeof(char);

    /**
     *  isRelated, true when Candidate is derived from Base OR Base is derived from Candidate
     */
    static const bool isRelated = isSub || InheritanceCheck<Base,Candidate>::isSub;
};


// Access policy for class InheritanceCheck in case of protected/private inheritance
#define ICP template<typename Candidate, typename Base> friend class InheritanceCheck

/* Example */
class A {};
class B : virtual A { ICP; };
class C : public virtual A, public B {};
struct D {};
struct S {};
class Z : public S {};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "B->A " << InheritanceCheck<B, A>::isSub << std::endl;
    std::cout << "C->A " << InheritanceCheck<C, A>::isSub << std::endl;
    std::cout << "C->B " << InheritanceCheck<C, B>::isSub << std::endl;
    std::cout << "D->A " << InheritanceCheck<D, A>::isSub << std::endl;
    std::cout << "A->B " << InheritanceCheck<A, B>::isSub << std::endl;
    std::cout << "A~B " << InheritanceCheck<A, B>::isRelated << std::endl;
    std::cout << "S->A " << InheritanceCheck<S, A>::isSub << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Z->S " << InheritanceCheck<Z, S>::isSub << std::endl;
}
```

**Output:**
B->A 1
C->A 1
C->B 1
D->A 0
A->B 0
A~B 1
S->A 0
Z->S 1